# keyboard shortcut to right alignment in XP (any text box)

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

Somehow I accident made text input in any text box becomes right alignment (OS-wide). I guess it might be 'windows+(somekey)' or 'ctrl+(somekey)'. Does anyone know this shortcut? and how to restore it back to default left alignment. Thanks!

Comment: Text boxes like on web sites? (That would be odd.)

Comment: (Not too odd, after doing some more testing given Bavi_H's answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps your computer has multiple languages installed and one is a right-to-left language? In Windows XP, you can set either Left Alt+Shift or Ctrl+Shift to change the language.

If the [Language Bar](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/keyboards/winkey.html#switch) is enabled, you can also click on it to change the language and keyboard layout.

Comment: I figured that when RTL (right-to-left) was enabled, *typing* would *.neht siht ekil gnihtemos dleiy* Likewise, I expected that *selecting* text would be from right to left as well. But though that is true for true RTL languages, typing and selecting does not seem to go backwards when typing LTR (left-to-right) within a RTL selection (try to select the text in "مرحبا العالم ، مرحبا missingspace ، لترى ما أعنيه." from http://translate.google.com/#en|ar|hello%20world%2C%20hello%20missingspace%2C%20to%20see%20what%20I%20mean to see what I mean.) So, I guess you're right, somehow RTL is activated!

Answer (score 8):

The shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Shift</kbd> to make the text right-to-left, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd> to make the text left-to-right again. This works in almost any text box.

This isn't related to the current input language. However, it only occurs if a right-to-left language is installed.

Comment: I believe that this is the answer to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 8):

For any text box, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for both alignments.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "OS-wide" hotkeys that will do this for **every** application, but in general, Microsoft typically uses these 3 shortcuts for text alignment in their programs:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>  - Align text left

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>  - Align text center

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>  - Align text right

Some programs will follow this and some won't. It's application specific really.

Comment: Spot on with those for apps, especially Word, PowerPoint, Outlook.
NB as well:
Ctrl + J = Justify

In OneNote, Ctrl+E jumps to the search box. Ctrl+J does not seem to do anything

In Excel:
Ctrl+L inserts a Table (2007, or a List in previous versions)
Ctrl+R is the fill-right feature (like Ctrl+D for fill down)
Ctrl+J, Ctrl+E doe nothing as far as I know.

As for OS-wide setting for alignment, no idea. Right-to-left language settings? Very weird.

Comment: Doesn't work in most software